# Enriching serilog logs in .net core 2 app is happening before authentication

Tags: .net-core, serilog

I've got a dotnet core 2 web app and I've configured SeriLog with the Enricher so I can log the user's email on each request, in the "Configure" method I have:

```
            // Log user
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            using (Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("UserId", context.User.Claims.Where(a => a.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).FirstOrDefault().Value))
            {
                await next.Invoke();
            }
        });

        app.UseMvc();
```

Unfortunately this is happening before authentication, so the Email is never set.

How do I get this to happen after authentication? Authentication is configured in the "ConfigureServices" method in the standard way like so:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue, needing to use authentication data in a custom middleware component.
Simply putting

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

before my custom *Use* middleware, populated the Context with relevant user data

Hope it helps.